# Zoom in to by name of location in openlayer 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to zoom in to location by name in sequence of state > district> village through dynamic select box.

In this one I have created two functions named `zoomToExtDist(name)` and `zoomToExtVil(distname,vilname)`. But don't know they are not working. Which function we should use in openlayers 3. Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong.
Here's the plunker I have created [zoom to location updated link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LF23hKkJMp481Tp5fgeB?p=preview)

Please tell me which function we should use to set the view through lat long in openlayers 3 .
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what errors do you have?

Comment: @madalinivascu it doesn't shows any error but when i check it through using alert box its not going into if condition

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rja2b1dLsJm7FDFtlUJ0?p=preview

Comment: don't just copy thing from the internet and clump them together and say that they didn't work

Comment: what exactly are you doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   $(function() {
    var records = jsonList.listval;
   // console.log(records);
    insert($('#state_id'), plucker(records, 'state'));
    //------------------------^ grabs unique states
    //--^ populate state list on DOM ready
    $('select').on('change', function() {
      var category = this.id.split('_id')[0];
      var value = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
      switch (category) {
        case 'state':
          {
            insert($('#district_id'), plucker(filter(records, 'state', value), 'district'));

             break;
          }
        case 'district':
          {
            insert($('#village_id'), plucker(filter(records, 'district', value), 'village'));
            break;
          }
          case 'village':
          {

             zoomToExtDist($(this).val());
            break;
          }
      }

  });


        function zoomToExtDist(name)
        { console.log(name);
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.listval.length; i++)
             {
              if(name==jsonList.listval[i].village)
              {
                  var tlon = parseFloat(jsonList.listval[i].longitude);
                  var tlat = parseFloat(jsonList.listval[i].latitude);
                  //var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(tlat,tlon);
                   map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.fromLonLat([tlat, tlon]));
                  map.getView().setZoom(5);

              }
             }

        }
....
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rja2b1dLsJm7FDFtlUJ0?p=preview

Comment: there are your coordinates, check them

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment because I don't have enough reputation, but in your plunkr I dont see the zoomtodist and zoomtovil functions? Which file are they in? Also, have you tried using the view.centerOn() [http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.View.html#centerOn]? Or the view.setCenter() and view.setZoom() separately to perform the centring and zoom?